# django: can I write python inside html template?

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% if request.session["user_name"] %}
<div class="abcd">user has username</div>
{% else %}
<div class="abcd">user doesn't has username</div>
{% endif %}
```

Is it illegal? There are errors:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /users/register/submit

Could not parse the remainder: '['user_name']' from 'request.session['user_name']'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly note that you need to pass the variables that are to be evaluated in the following fashion.

**Your python script**

```
template_values = {
        'message': 'Invalid credentials, please try again'
            'users': users
}

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'login.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

**The template file**

```
{% ifequal users.name "name" %}
<div class="abcd">user has username</div>
{% endifequal %}
```

Please check the [django template docs](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/) for further clarification based on the version that your using.

Answer (score 10):

Django doc says :

> Django template system is not simply Python embedded into HTML

Which means that you cannot write Python.

However talking about variables, the [doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) also says this :

> Behind the scenes
>
> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute lookup
> - Method call
> - List-index lookup

Which means that what you are trying is possible, but the right syntax is :

```
{% if request.session.user_name %}
```